# Amazon api gateway doesn`t pass to lambda requests if x-amz-target header contains dot

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I try to make smart proxy for Amazon Certificate Manager with few filters.
Schema should looks like:

```
client -> Api Gateway (with authorization) -> Lambda function -> ACM
```

It works fine with disabled authorization. But then I enable authorization I start getting error:
`{'Message': 'The service name : "BackplaneExecutionService" identified from the payload does not agree with the service name : "CertificateManager" specified in the transport header'}`
This is my test code on python:

```
auth = requests_aws4auth.AWS4Auth(access_key, secret_key, "eu-west-1", "execute-api", )
req = requests.Request('POST', url=BASE_URL, json=data, auth=auth, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "X-Amz-Target": "CertificateManager.RequestCertificate"})
```

But if I try x-amz-target without dot - it passes to lambda.
Can somebody give me idea how to save transparent compatibility with existed instruments like aws cli.

Comment: Can you try `content-type` as `application/x-amz-json-1.1` and see if it changes anything? Also add the sample `data` that you have passed

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: any update? @mr_tron